# QString with text and an image

Tags: qt4, qstring, qpixmap

Is there a way of inserting an image in a QString?
I need to have a QString this way " 'image' some text"

It needs to be a QString since i'm inserting it in a QPaint event and i 
cant use a QLabel for that (because i can't insert a qlabel into the painting area)

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No, a string is a string. Use an image or pixmap to paint images.

Comment: I think you want `QTextDocument` (or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QString` only contain and display text. If you want do do such a thing, you can write rich text in your `QString` (with HTML syntax) and display it in a component with is able to display rich text (here `QGraphicsTextItem` because you seem to work in a scene) :

```
QString myRichText = "<img src=\"URL or URI of the image\"/> some text";
QGraphicsTextItem textDisplayer(myRichText);
// Hack, hack, hack in your scene
```